# How to append number to list in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I am very new to Prolog. My goal is to append integers to a list, up to a bound:
if the function receives `N`, it outputs a list `[N, N-1, ... , 1]`.

Here is my code:

```
myAppend(0, L) :- append([],[], L).
myAppend(N, L) :- append([N], [], L), N1 is N - 1, myAppend(N1, L).
```

invoking the function above returns false for every `N=\=0`:

```
51 ?- myAppend(0,L).
L = [] ;
false.

52 ?- myAppend(2,L).
false. <-------------------- was expecting L = [2, 1]

53 ?-
```

However, when i changed my function to (put a dot `.` instead of `,` after call to `append` in the 2nd rule):

```
myAppend(0, L) :- append([],[],L).
myAppend(N,L) :-  append([N], [], L). N1 is N - 1, myAppend(N1, L).
```

I got the following output:

```
51 ?- myAppend(0,L).
L = [] ;
false.

52 ?- myAppend(4,L).
L = [4] . <-------------- was expecting [4, 3, 2, 1]

53 ?-
```

I am unable to understand why in the 1st implementation I was receiving `false`, although the logic behind it is correct?

Comment: What are you expecting from `append([N],[],L)`? do you know what `append/3` does? do you have any notion of _unification?_

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, yes, i am using it in order to append a single number to the list. as a case in point, i managed to do that after i modified the code as i showed in the question above. it appends [N] to [  ] and put the result in L.

Comment: Are you aware that changing the `,` to a `.` changed one rule into two rules? Did you not get the error message `Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2` when you did the change?

Comment: What about `myAppend(2,L)`? `myAppend(2,L)` will first unify `L` using `append([2],[],L)`, i.e., `L` unifies with `[2]` and then will call the goal `append([1],[],L)`, which is true if and only if `L` unifies with `[1]`, which is false, since `L` unifies with `[2]`. If you want to use recursion, you'll need an accumulator. If you understand what `append/3` does, you probably understand why it's completely useless in your case: your use of `append/3` is equivalent to `L=[N]`.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
myAppend(0, []).

myAppend(N, [N | L]) :-
  N > 0,
  N1 is N - 1,
  myAppend(N1, L).
```

?

Comment: i added `append([N],L,L),` after the line `N1 is N -1` and replaced 1st line by `range(0, L) :- L= [].`. The output i got was `L = [5|**] .` for calling `myAppend(N,5).`. How can I view that the list contains all the numbers? (i.e. unroll the `**`)

Comment: @ThunderWing `append([N], L, L)` is asking for a list `L` such that `L` appended to `[N]` gives `L` back again, that is `L = [N|L]`. The solution to that is a *cyclic term* (term that recursively refers to itself). Is that what you want? Why do you want or need to use `append/3` rather than the solution that max66 has shown?